# Wix creates an application data directory which is read only

Tags: wix

I'm creating a folder structure in WiX in the following manner:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp">
  </Directory>
</Directory>
<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
  <Directory Id="CONFIGFOLDER" Name="MyAppConfig">
    <Directory Id="Configdir1" Name="Configdir1">
    </Directory>        
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="MyApp"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I'm then populating these directories later on using Component tags like this:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductConfiguration" Directory="CONFIGFOLDER">         
  <Component Id="ConfigFile1" Guid="*">
    <File Id="ConfigFile1.xml" Name="ConfigFile1.xml" Source="..\Configuration\ConfigFile1.xml" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ConfigFile2" Guid="*">
    <File Id="ConfigFile2.xml" Name="ConfigFile2.xml" Source="..\Configuration\ConfigFile2.xml" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="ConfigFile3" Guid="*">
    <File Id="ConfigFile3.xml" Name="ConfigFile3.xml" Source="..\Configuration\ConfigFile3.xml" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

My problem is this:  WiX creates the Configuration directory (`CommonAppDataFolder/MyAppConfig`) as a read only folder.  Since it's full of application data, users need to be able to modify its contents without having admin privileges.  I can create other folders in the `CommonAppDataFolder` programmatically, which do not require admin privileges.

How do I set the write privileges for my folder in WiX?

Comment: The answers to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272406/wix-how-to-set-permissions-for-folder-and-all-sub-folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the answer looks something like this:

```
      <Directory Id="MYFOLDER" Name="My folder name">
        <Component Id="MyFolderComponent" Guid="*">
          <CreateFolder Directory="MYFOLDER">
            <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
          </CreateFolder>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

CommonAppDataFolder is a per-machine store and so requires elevated privileges to write to. If you want a per-user store, use the AppDataFolder or LocalAppDataFolder directory properties instead.

Comment: Is there a place that all users can write to?