# How to set permissions for directory

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I followed the SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272406/wix-how-to-set-permissions-for-folder-and-all-sub-folders) to add permission to a folder. However if I would like to set permission for directory, what can I do?

For example, in the link it has the following code:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
  <Directory Id="PHPFolder" Name="PHP">
    <Component Id="PHP_comp" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
      <CreateFolder>
        <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
      </CreateFolder>
```

How can I set permission for directory PHPFolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try with a [**CreateFolder Element**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/createfolder.html):

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Myfolder">
 <Component Feature="ProductFeature">
   <File Source="TestFile.exe" />
   <CreateFolder>
     <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes"/>
   </CreateFolder>
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

***General Tip***: Try to pillage [github.com](https://www.github.com) for snippets when you are stuck. [Random Sample](https://github.com/aerobase/omnibus-aerobase-server/blob/ccbfb0a1b1d028fc2a5a350731a2b2a01f3c5325/resources/aerobase/msi/source.wxs.erb).

---

***Further Links***:

- [Several ways to apply permissions in WiX (mid page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324552/is-wix-changing-the-permissions-on-my-notes-ini-file/49325684#49325684)
- **[How to deny folder permission to Users with wix installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543312/how-to-deny-folder-permission-to-users-with-wix-installer/49546999#49546999)**
- [System.UnauthorizedAccessException while running .exe under program files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587622/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-running-exe-under-program-files/50588465#50588465)

Comment: CreateFolder works. I also need to set Component Id and Guid in my case. Thanks much!

Comment: [Most component GUIDs can be auto-generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732761/syntax-for-guids-in-wix/24769965#24769965). Please be advised that it is generally better to use other permissioning constructs than the Permission element. See the list of ways in the link above. For simple permissions the Permission element should work I think.

Comment: I try to use auto-generated GUID first. However it pops up error say Component using a Directory as KeyPath or containing ODBCDataSource child elements cannot use auto-generate GUID. And actually I am using util:PermissionEx instead of Permission. Thanks much for you advice, Stein.

Comment: Yes, that happens if you have no files in the component or a custom TARGETDIR pointing to D: drives or similar - and a few other cases. Glad it is working, best of luck with the rest.