# Unable to write file in using cacls.exe

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, file-permissions, cacls

For installation using .NET, I wish to give write permission to a particular file in the folder using cacls.exe, so I have referred [How to give Read/Write permissions to a Folder during installation using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288444/how-to-give-read-write-permissions-to-a-folder-during-installation-using-net) and I have used the code from [Setting File or Directory permissions ACE entries with .NET using CACLS.EXE](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2004/Nov/06/Setting-File-or-Directory-permissions-ACE-entries-with-NET-using-CACLSEXE). 
After installation, on form load, I could read the file *file.txt* which is located at C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyProduct , with below code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Some code

DirectoryPermission dp = new
DirectoryPermission(filename, "Everyone", "F");
dp.SetAce();
foffset = read_file();          

}
string filename = "file.txt";
private double read_file()
{

double value = 0;
try
{
    value = Double.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@filename));
    return value;
}
catch
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@filename, value.ToString());
    return 0;
}
}
```

But on a button click I couldn't write the file with new value, so I wrote the below code and did installation, still the problem persist:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try{        
DirectoryPermission dp = new
DirectoryPermission(filename , "Everyone", "F");
dp.SetAce();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@filename , offset.ToString());

}
catch
 {}
}
```

I'm giving full control to all the users, but I'm not able to write the file. and I'm getting this error

```
  Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What tool are you using? [For WiX maybe check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702972/how-to-set-permissions-for-directory/53710174#53710174).

Comment: @SonalBorkar `Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I'm using [Xcacls.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=19419) .

Comment: @user2587 you will need Administrator permission to write anything inside Program Files folder. Giving permission only to file will not work. Program must have permission in Parent directory too.

Comment: @SonalBorkar This task may be tedious, maybe I will install the software in another location in C:.